# How to create csv file in iphone programmatically?

Tags: iphone, csv

I want to convert a database table into a csv file in Iphone. I want to attach the csv file in mail, so it can be viewed in excel sheet in a table form. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 3):

you should have a look at [CHCSVParser](https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) made by Dave Delong. Ignore the name, it's a writer, too.

It's working great; until you want to support the german (and others) csv format, which uses semicolons

Comment: How to give input to the CHCSV Writter?

Comment: Create a NSArray (for the rows) of NSArrays (for the columns) and then you can use the NSArray category method `writeToCSVFile:atomically:` from NSArray+CHCSVAdditions.h. But there are other ways, please refer to the readme of CHCSVParser

Answer (score 1):

Hey I Found Simple Code ::

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory , NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *root = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"customers.csv"];

        NSString *temp;

        temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [arrCustomersName objectAtIndex:0]];

        for (int i = 1; i < [arrCustomersName count]; i++) {

            temp = [temp stringByAppendingFormat:@", %@", [arrCustomersName objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

        [temp writeToFile:root atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```